# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_NativeStripeSdk.default.initialise') In react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

[image]

I am trying to link stripe payment to react native expo using the `@stripe/stripe-react-native` package but i am getting error while providing publishable key to stripe provider element

Answer (score 0):

You need to update to the latest version of Expo.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native#typeerror-null-is-not-an-object-evaluating-_nativestripesdkdefaultinitialise-on-android

Comment: I update expo 43.0.0 to 46.0.0 after I run I show only blank screen what issue @karllekko??

Comment: Hard to say without more details like exact code, error messages from the console, etc. I'd suggest doing some debugging and opening a new question if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like, SDK is not initialised properly.
SDK functions call before SDK is initialised Please follow the steps of SDK
configuration.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/stripe-react-native